# web view not loading url

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, uicollectionview

I am using Collection view, I have 6 cells in collective view and I want to present different url on cell click, how can i do it? with the help of array of urls? or is there another way to do it?

FirstViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    array=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"home.jpg",@"about-us.png",@"aarti.png",@"video.png",@"news.png",@"contact.png", nil];


    NSString *url1=@"url1";
    NSString *url2=@"url2";
    NSString *url3=@"url3";
    NSString *url4=@"url4";
    NSString *url5=@"url5";
    NSString *url6=@"url6";

    urls=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:url1,url2,url3,url4,url5,url6, nil];

}
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return array.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *identifier = @"collect";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {

  NSString *urlAddress = [urls objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];//url at clicked index from array

  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

  WebViewController *webView=[[WebViewController alloc]init];
  NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
  [webView.webview loadRequest:requestObj];

}
```

Comment: read about any mvc structure or a collectionview tutorial

Comment: @Shubhank yes i have create collection view having 6 cells and now i want to present 6 urls on web view,i have created web view and successfully presenting and URL but i don't know how to present different URL ,respect of index of cell.

Comment: there is a delegate method of collection `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` here you can get the url for the position and show it in the webview or pass in segue whatever you want.

Comment: @Shubhank i know about this method, but i have 6 URLs for each of the cell, how can i show different URL on cell click ?

Comment: can you upload a screenshot of what is your UI and what values you have ?

Comment: @Shubhank i have added the code in question, i have 6 cells and 6 URLs which i want to present in web view, i just want to know how can i present each URL on a cell click, like when i click cell at index 0 it should present URL 1 ,how to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CollectionView Delegate method `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` and according to `indexPath` reload `UIWebView` with Url at `indexPath.row` from array of Urls.

Like,

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {

   NSString *urlAddress = [arrUrl objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]//url at clicked index from array

   //Create a URL object.
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

   //URL Request Object
   NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

   //Load the request in the UIWebView.
   [YourWebViewObject loadRequest:requestObj];

 }
```

Comment: how can i create array of URLs ?

Comment: store the url strings into array, urls with same count to your collectionview cell count@Shikha

Comment: WC...mark it as answer if helped so it can help others too:)@Shikha

Comment: than pass selected row url to secondVC and load webview with that url.

Comment: web view is not loading url :(

Comment: @Shikha if it is not loading yet then please follow two points  --> Step1 : use webview delegate method     - (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
   NSLog(@"Error : %@",error);
}
Step 2- Cross check about webview delegate in webview controller must be connect if webview is added in webviewcontroller via IB either via programmatically

Comment: @sandy Error : Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=101 "(null)"
checkout my code above. is it correct ?

Comment: @Shikha use this before creating the URL NSString *encodedString=[siteUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *weburl = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedString];

Comment: @Shikha then must check with webview delegate that you are using in webviewcontroller

Comment: @Shikha oh i saw your code how you use webviewcontroller in collection view , is it in IB or just creating here programmatically?

Comment: @Shikha why you are not trying to add a webview directly under  collectionview cell "collect" in storyboard?

Comment: @sandy i am using storyboard and it's delegate is connected, i have imported webviewcontroller in firstviewcontroller, and i did't get you.

Comment: @Shikha when you are selecting any cell the weviewcontroller is opening or not ? if it is opening then only facing issue with loading that url right ?

Comment: @sandy it is openin